# Is there a way to incrementally increase count in a recursion?

Tags: javascript, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

**Is there a way to incrementally increase the count for the Tower of Hanoi challenge?**

At the moment, the count isn't incrementally increasing. Interestingly, it starts at five and hops around. See the output below.

I tried adding a `let count = 0` within the function and adding `++count` within the IF statement and outside the recursive function to no avail.

Working code block:

```
const move = (n, source, destination, buffer, count) => {

  // Verify that there are disks.
  if (n > 0) {

    // Move one disk to buffer rod.
    move(n - 1, source, buffer, destination, ++count);

    // Move nth disk from source to destination.
    destination.push(source.pop())

    // Display progress
    console.log(count, A, B, C, "\n--------------------------")

    // Move the disk (n - 1) from the buffer to the destination.
    move(n - 1, buffer, destination, source, ++count);
  }
};

// Disk starting position
const A = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
const B = []
const C = []

// Invoke
move(5, A, C, B, 0);
```

Output:

```
5 [ 5, 4, 3, 2 ] [] [ 1 ] 
--------------------------
4 [ 5, 4, 3 ] [ 2 ] [ 1 ] 
--------------------------
6 [ 5, 4, 3 ] [ 2, 1 ] [] 
--------------------------
3 [ 5, 4 ] [ 2, 1 ] [ 3 ] 
--------------------------
6 [ 5, 4, 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ] 
--------------------------
5 [ 5, 4, 1 ] [] [ 3, 2 ] 
--------------------------
7 [ 5, 4 ] [] [ 3, 2, 1 ] 
--------------------------
2 [ 5 ] [ 4 ] [ 3, 2, 1 ] 
--------------------------
6 [ 5 ] [ 4, 1 ] [ 3, 2 ] 
--------------------------
5 [ 5, 2 ] [ 4, 1 ] [ 3 ] 
--------------------------
7 [ 5, 2, 1 ] [ 4 ] [ 3 ] 
--------------------------
4 [ 5, 2, 1 ] [ 4, 3 ] [] 
--------------------------
7 [ 5, 2 ] [ 4, 3 ] [ 1 ] 
--------------------------
6 [ 5 ] [ 4, 3, 2 ] [ 1 ] 
--------------------------
```

Comment: Use a preassigned parameter maybe? So replace count with count = 0 in your function signature. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Comment: @Berk I tried count = 0 and the output is the same. Would adding a preassigned parameter change the outcome even if the invocation includes 0?

Comment: I mean, it starts from 0 then you are incrementing it respectively, if you were to assign it to 0 inside the function it would be 0 each time the recursion occurs, this way you are able increment the value, that was my approach.

Answer (score 0):

Return the value of `count` and assign it back to the variable.

```js
const move = (n, source, destination, buffer, count) => {

  // Verify that there are disks.
  if (n > 0) {

    // Move one disk to buffer rod.
    count = move(n - 1, source, buffer, destination, ++count);

    // Move nth disk from source to destination.
    destination.push(source.pop())

    // Display progress
    console.log(count, JSON.stringify(A), JSON.stringify(B), JSON.stringify(C), "\n--------------------------")

    // Move the disk (n - 1) from the buffer to the destination.
    count = move(n - 1, buffer, destination, source, ++count);
    
  }
  return count;
};

// Invocate
const A = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
const B = []
const C = []

move(5, A, C, B, 0);
```